# Как организовать базу данных?

Tags: база-данных

У меня есть веб-приложение для решения математических задач. Пользователи регистрируются, могут создавать свои задачи и решать чужие. На данный момент у меня есть таблица юзеров и связь one-to-many к задачам. Теперь мне нужно организовать отношение, которое бы показывало, у кого эта данная математическая задачка решена. Как нужно организовать базу?

Comment: Похоже, нужна связь many-to-many. В промежуточной таблице кроме двух колонок с айдишниками будет ещё одна с признаком решено или нет.

Comment: первые две вам тоже подсказали? заведи третью таблицу id_user, id_task, solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать связь many-to-many, путем создания таблицы, которая будет хранить два значения: id пользователя и id задачи, которую он уже решил. И пусть оба столбца составляют первичный ключ в виде пары значений.